# What is application-icon-65534 in android? How does it work?

Tags: android, gradle, aapt, android-mipmap

When I ran the command `aapt dump badging my_apk.apk` , I can find the application icons for different screen resolutions:

```
application-icon-160:'res/mipmap-mdpi-v4/ic_launcher.png'
application-icon-240:'res/mipmap-hdpi-v4/ic_launcher.png'
application-icon-320:'res/mipmap-xhdpi-v4/ic_launcher.png'
application-icon-480:'res/mipmap-xxhdpi-v4/ic_launcher.png'
application-icon-65534:'res/mipmap-mdpi-v4/ic_launcher.png'
application: label='MyAppName' icon='res/mipmap-mdpi-v4/ic_launcher.png'
```

The `application-icon-160`, `application-icon-240` and so on obviously stand for `mdpi`, `hdpi` and so on. But I don't understand what `application-icon-65534` stands for. And strangely it's linked to the `mdpi` icon, how can I link it to `xxhdpi`?

Comment: I've just found that application-icon-65535 stands for nodpi. I suppose application-icon-65534 stands for anydpi.